# How to setting test runner in unity 2018 , And dont rebuild my assetbundle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

, when I run a test runner , in unity 2018.4.3 it have to create a Assembly Definition to test ,
I need "test my game logic" ,So I have to references "assembly-CShrap.dll" but I can't find that !!
[image: upload_2019-9-19_9-42-48.png]

So I have a tricky solution like that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions...nity-and-fix-missing-assembly-reference-error

I create a new Assemlby define to in include all script
[image: upload_2019-9-19_9-50-46.png]
and reference to test assemlby define
[image: upload_2019-9-19_9-51-16.png]
Ok it work , But when I load assetbundle Get this error meesage!

A scripted object (probably UIButton?) has a different serialization layout when loading. (Read 32 bytes but expected 344 bytes)
Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?
UnityEngine.AssetBundle:get_mainAsset()

It look like myAssembly define changed , And My "Old Assetbundle" can not load sccuess ,
So I dont want to rebuild all Assetbundle , So how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I Found soultion : `TestRunner -> EditorMode -> Enable playmode tests for all assmblies`
[image]
Play mode also , But have to reopen Unity after setting